# How to extract specific numbers from a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
a = array([[100.        , 100.        , 100.        ],
   [175.24163615, 198.31220183,  32.71406333],
   [150.36778472,  82.62453566,  38.51860719],
   [ 155.28247936,  191.50455896,  23.09254829],
   [ 36.4302652 ,  67.34580186,  30.82481977]])
```

What I do is that I check each column and if the number in the third row is greater then 100 I change it into 21.75; if the number in the fourth row is greater then 100 I change it into 29. For this, I use the following code:

```
Z1[2]=[21.75 if x>100 else x for x in Z1[2]]
Z1[3]=[29 if x>100 else x for x in Z1[3]]
```

What I am struggling with is to do the following. Once there is a change, I want to create an array with the changed number (only the first one in a given row) and if there is no change take the last one of a given row. Say, for the matrix above by running the code I will receive:

```
a = array([[100.        , 100.        , 100.        ],
   [175.24163615, 198.31220183,  32.71406333],
   [21.75,  82.62453566,  38.51860719],
   [ 29,  29,  23.09254829],
   [ 36.4302652 ,  67.34580186,  30.82481977]])
```

So, the final array should look like:

```
a = array([21.75, 29, 30.82481977])
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: yes, thanks, I edited the thread

Comment: why 30.82481977 ?